# Мониторинг работы процесса

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, процесс

Как мне сделать что бы программа постоянно проверяла запущен ли процесс X и записывала это в переменную Y при этом программа должна дальше выполнять свои функции? Просто всю программу мне зацикливать нельзя, а проверять процесс X надо

Comment: Гуглите в сторону многопоточности

Comment: В чём конкретно сложность?

Comment: Сложность в том что я глупенький и не знаю как это сделать

Comment: SO помогает определить проблемы с кодом, а не с личностными качествами людей. Что **конкретно** Вы не знаете, как сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если возиться с многопоточностью - слишком сложно, то, имхо, имеет смысл выполнять проверку не постоянно в цикле, а поместить её в функцию, чтобы она выполнялась только когда этот результат нужен.

То есть, вместо того, чтобы писать результат в переменную Y, вы можете создать функцию y(), поместить в неё то, что у вас было внутри цикла (только уже без циклы), и чтобы эта функция делала return того результата, который раньше вы писали в переменную Y.

И после этого всюду, где вы обращались к переменной Y, вы теперь просто обращаетесь к y()